# Для чего нужны интерфейсы IEqualityComparer и IStructuralEquatable в C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Не особо понимаю в чём преимущества использования данных интерфейсов и где в C# я могу их использовать. Так-же, как я понял - IEqualityComparer используют коллекции которые работают на базе хэш-таблиц, но не совсем понимаю зачем и какие выгоды это дает.
Буду очень признателен за прояснение ситуации!

Comment: Похожие вопросы [How to use the IEqualityComparer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6694508/312041), [What problem does IStructuralEquatable and IStructuralComparable solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3609823/312041)

Comment: Смотрел справку? [IEqualityComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=net-7.0)  [IStructuralEquatable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.istructuralequatable?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Мне кажется, что затруднение состоит в понимании назначения этих интерфейсов. В справке по ссылке [IEqualityComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=net-7.0) ключевая фраза - это "This is consistent with the Contains, IndexOf, LastIndexOf, and Remove methods of the Dictionary<TKey,TValue> class and other generic collections." То есть смысл этих интерфейсов состоит в том, что они используются библиотечными классами, и поэтому ими нужно пользоваться для поддержки функциональности стандартных коллекций. А поддержка состоит в том, что есть возможность модифицировать поведение стандартного класса для объекта. Предоставляя объекту свою реализацию интерфейса IEqualityComparer, мы заставляем его сравнивать объекты так, как нужно нам, а не каким-то стандартным образом.

Никто не заставляет использовать эти интерфейсы в собственных классах, но их использование обеспечивает некоторую стандартизацию, что является полезным.